# Where can I view my HD wallet seed in bitcoin core 13.2

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip32-hd-wallets, seed

Where/how do I view my seed in core 13.2? I understand that as of 13.0, the hd wallets are used by default.

Answer (score 7):

To get the extended private masterkey itself (not a seed), you can use the `dumpwallet` command and provide it with a filename to dump your keys to. The extended master key will be at the top of the file, and then it will list all addresses along with their keypaths underneath that, line by line.

Note that the dumped file is not encrypted, so be careful with what you do with it :)

Comment: could you write how to restore wallet from such master key ? I'm looking for paper backup of core wallet

Comment: @Pavel Niedoba, please ask that as a separate question :)